# Does the screen need to be detached to keep the process running after disconnection

Tags: gnu-screen

My ssh connection is unreliable, so I've been studiously using screen and detaching every time I start a long-running process. The screen part I know is necessary, but is the detaching as well? Thanks.

Comment: if you start the screen as dettached, that screen session will remain active even after you get disconnected from your ssh connection. The only way the screen session stops working is if someone SSHs into the machine your working on and does a screen wipe of all active sessions

Comment: @ryekayo What if I'm still attached to the screen when I get disconnected? That's the question.

Comment: No it is still active. Stays active even after you get disconnected. Like I said, only way it gets disconnected is if someone goes into the machine and does a screen wipe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to disconnect, if the connection gets interrupted you can use `screen -dr` to reattach to a already running screen session that wasn't properly disconnected from first.

Simply list out the screen sessions using `screen -ls`:

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    10266.somesession   (Attached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-slm.
```

Note the sessions name, `10266.somesession` and reattach to it like so:

```
$ screen -dr 10266.somesession
```

**NOTE:** So long as the other system where `screen` is running is not rebooted or the parent process that owns `screen` is not killed, your screen sessions will remain intact.